# How can I store more than 8000 bytes of data inline in a SQL Server 2012 row?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a small blog engine. I would love to find a sample SQL Server schema to give me some ideas but have yet to find one.

I would like to have a blog table that allows me to store more than 8000 bytes of data. Can anyone tell me if a good way to do this would with two fields like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Blog](
 [BlogId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [BlogText1] [nvarchar](8000) NOT NULL,
 [BlogText2] [nvarchar](8000),
 ..
```

What I was thinking was to store the text in two fields and have my application append the contents of the two fields when it was displaying the data and when storing data have the first xxx characters stored in BlogText1 and then any remainder stored in BlogText2.

Is this a reasonable thing to do or should I just use a nvarchar(max)?

If I use nvarchar(8000) how many characters can I fit into that?

What I am concerned about is the time it will take to retrieve a row. Am I correct in assuming that if I use nvarchar(max) it will take much longer to retrieve the row.

Comment: Here is an example schema http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and get it working first. Only after it's working should you profile to test if the column width is a performance bottleneck. My guess is that it won't be, but you'll never know until after the app is working.

Comment: user2246674 - You mention more than ~8000 cannot be stored inline. I thought with SQL Server 2012 there was a very large amount of bytes that could be stored with row overflow. Is it not possible to store those > 8000 in multiple fields and use row overflow without having to use MAX?

Comment: @Gemma http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx "SQL Server supports row-overflow storage which enables *variable length* columns [like NVARCHAR(MAX)] to be pushed off-row." This is talking about NVARCHAR(MAX)-like columns present since 2005 (?) and is not new for 2012.

Comment: The base storage element in SQL Server (even in version 2012) is a **8192 byte** page - this size is fixed, cannot be changed. Some overhead reduces this size to **8060 usable bytes** per page - more **CANNOT** be stored inline. Larger chunks will be stored in **overflow pages** (but not **inline**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version - use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` until you identify that there is a definite performance problems to solve - attempting to manually split up large blog entries so that they are saved "inline" is almost certainly going to result in worse performance than leaving it up to SQL Server.

---

The long version - SQL Server stores data up in 8060 byte size chunks called [pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Normally the length of an individual column cannot exceed this size, however certain large-value types (e.g. `TEXT`) can be handled specially and their value replace with a 24-byte pointer to the actual data which is stored elsewhere (in the `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` allocation unit)

The `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data types actually provide a hybrid approach - in the case where the data is small enough the value is stored in the Data pages as it would be normally, however when the data is too large it is seamlessly converted into a large-value type for you.  This generally means you get the best of both worlds.